# Controllers and ajax in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I'm new at Laravel and I can't figure how to handle controllers (and ajax).
I have a button in a sidebar, and I want to show a page when it's clicked.

I have a view (which is the page i want to display in ajax) located in views/logs/system.blade.php
and a controller located in controllers/LogsController which has the following code -

```
class LogsController extends BaseController {
    public function getLogs() {
        return View::make('logs/system');
    }
}
```

my routes.php has the code -

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome'); // Works fine
Route::get('logs', 'LogsController@getLogs');
```

First things - how can I access the view I'm gettings in getLogs in a URL (localhost/mysite/public/logs doesn't work...)
Second - how can I access it in an ajax call?

I tried
      $.get('logs', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

but it doesn't work either. It gets 500 Internal Server Error....
Help please!

Comment: Have you tried to visit the 'logs' URL before making an AJAX request to it? If so, do you see any Laravel information about the error or just your web server error page? I've duplicated your code and it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to: localhost/mysite/public/logs

if not, enable mod_rewrite in your apache and in your apache httpd.conf, set:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the server error 500 (in both cases) is caused by the fact that you have a mistake in the View::make() call. To utilize a view in subfolder you have to use the dot notation.

So correct the code

```
class LogsController extends BaseController {
    public function getLogs() {
        return View::make('logs.system');
    }
}
```

and you should be good to go, the url should load fine, both in browser and in Ajax.

If you still have problems, check the Laravel Logs (probably path/to/app/storage/logs/...) as well as Apache Error Log (probably /var/log/apache2/error.log). I assume you are using Unix/Linux operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite module was on.

I solved it by going to localhost/mysite/public/**index.php**/logs, this is the URL that it expects, maybe something in the .htaccess file is wrong.